ECONNREFUSED when connecting to EC2 instance programmatically via nodejs, works in shell
I have written some js code that creates an instance in a specified region.
It creates a new security group and private key file, then creates the instance with those set up.
The security group is set to allow ssh traffic from anywhere.
async function authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(ec2, groupId) {
  try {
    const params = {
      GroupId: groupId,
      IpPermissions: [
        {
          IpProtocol: "tcp",
          FromPort: 22, // SSH
          ToPort: 22,
          IpRanges: [{ CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0" }], // Allow SSH access from anywhere 
        }
      ],
    };

    await ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(params).promise();
    console.log("Ingress rule added to security group.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error authorizing ingress:", err);
    throw err;
  }
}

After the instance is running:
function waitForInstanceRunning(ec2, instanceId) {
  const params = {
    InstanceIds: [instanceId],
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ec2.waitFor("instanceRunning", params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}

I use ssh2 to ssh into the instance and execute commands.
// modify permissions of the file to 600
        chmod600(pemFilePath).then(()=>{
          const connSettings = {
            host: publicIpAddress,
            port: 22, // Standard SSH port
            username: 'ubuntu',
            privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync(pemFilePath) 
          };
          const conn = new Client();
          conn.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('SSH connection established');

            conn.exec(command, (err, stream) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              stream.on('close', (code, signal) => {
                console.log('Stream closed');
                conn.end();
              }).on('data', (data) => {
                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
              }).stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
              });
            });
          }).connect(connSettings);

          conn.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Error: ', err);
          });
        })

publicIpAdress is correct, pemFilePath is correct, and the chmod600 function does work (all previously tested)
Everything in the code works:
Key pair created: dep_kp_97zlncl1yf9
Private key uploaded to S3 bucket 'deploykps' with key keyPairs/dep_kp_97zlncl1yf9.pem
Local private key file dep_kp_97zlncl1yf9.pem deleted.
Security group created: sg-0144a5cfc4765cf2a
Ingress rule added to security group.
Instance created: i-05f7c65f29b6b714e
Instance is running: i-05f7c65f29b6b714e
sending test command `echo 'hello world' > ~/test.txt`
Starting command execution on instance i-05f7c65f29b6b714e

`echo 'hello world' > ~/test.txt`
Found public IP 54.241.142.163
PEM file downloaded from S3 bucket 'deploykps' with key keyPairs/dep_kp_97zlncl1yf9.pem
Permissions set to 600 successfully for dep_kp_97zlncl1yf9.pem
Error:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.241.142.163:22
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '54.241.142.163',
  port: 22,
  level: 'client-socket'
}

ChatGPT says the issue could be any of the following:

ssh not enabled on the EC2 instance
-> not possible, otherwise the subsequent ssh in my own shell wouldnt work either
incorrect IP addr/host
-> same as previous
firewall/network configuration
-> same as previous + I double checked all security group and ACL rules... both allow SSH traffic from everywhere (0.0.0.0/0)
ssh key auth
-> not a problem, the same key was used in my shell

(Basically chatGPT was useless)
I have tried with the latest node version (20.12.1) and fresh ssh2 installs, same problem.
Also tried in multipl enviroments (Replit, AWS instance, no access to my personal machine at the moment, but it should be identical to the AWS instance in terms of how things run)
AWS instance was a t2.micro
If you want the full code for reference, here it is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gUsDLPRn5f6X_Br8unAjsafOLKTsiAv7/view?usp=sharing
(Bucket name is unimportant, just a public bucket I had lying around)
Also open to suggestions for easier ways to run bash commands on an ec2 instance from nodejs.

Where is the code the launches the instance?  What platform/AMI is this instance?

ope... the bucket seems to be restricted... my bad. I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type ami-05c969369880fa2c2`. I will update the link in the post

It might be obvious but just because you didn't mention it:
For when the configured authentication method is trough keys, you usually need to add the public key in the .ssh/authorized_keys for the intended user in the EC2 instance.
Hope it helps.

does it not configure this by defualt?

you are corret, it does for the default user.

Then that is not the issue... as for now I think the issue is that the instance needs to boot up OpenSSH on its end, so I just wait for everything to come online.
